# Automatically perform C# wrapping of a C++ library

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I've done a bit of research around this before posting but I couldn't find a direct answer specific to my environment.

I have a third party library written in C++. I have access to the `.dll`, `.lib` and `.h` headers of the library.

I'd like to wrap the library for use in C# using p/invoke. I'd like to know what options I have in terms of doing this *and* maintaining it. My hope here is that with the `.h` headers I can utilize some application to automatically provide the wrapper code.

I'm interested in all kinds of solutions including commercial software solutions and any pitfalls of trying to automatically manage the wrapper code.

Comment: Will the [DllImport] not sufficient for your needs?

Comment: @GeraldSv: That would require me to manually write all the functions I require (All of them) out of the DLL would it not?

Comment: @S.Richmond: Oh yeah, you're looking for automation solution so this would not do it.

Comment: Quick googling gave me this: http://www.pinvoker.com/

Comment: @elgonzo - Yeah I just found that myself. Testing it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My hope here is that with the .h headers I can utilize some application to automatically provide the wrapper code.

It would be lovely if this were possible, but it is not. It is not possible because the header file does not contain enough information to determine how to marshal parameters. For instance, consider this declaration:

```
void foo(int *x);
```

What is `x`? Its type is `int*`, pointer to `int`. But is it a pointer to a single `int` value, or is it an array of `int`? You simply cannot tell from the header file. You need to read the documentation.

And what about data flow. Is the information flowing into the native code, or out of it, or in both directions? Again, that detail cannot be expressed a header file.

Now, there are various annotation conventions that can help with this. Essentially these are macros that evaluate to nothing that can be read by a tool and so help with conversion. You see Win32 API functions annotated with `_In_`, `_In_Opt_`, etc. These can help, but only the very simplest of libraries can be automatically translated into p/invoke declarations.

Now, if you are prepared to add extra annotation to the raw header files then you might have a chance. It is certainly possible that existing tools exist that will do a good job so long as you express the missing information in comments or macros. SWIG is certainly worth a look, and there are other tools.

The fundamental point of my answer is to try to get across the idea that such translations are not as automatic as you might hope. Personally, I always end up writing my p/invoke declarations by hand. This allows me to get them exactly the way I want, and maintenance is not really a big deal because DLL interfaces typically don't change. They don't change because you don't want to break binary compatibility.

Comment: Thanks David. I think this was the kind of answer I was expecting to get, but without the knowledge myself I needed it validated before I went any further (Or in this case, stopping all together).

Answer (score 4):

You could try [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) which is free. You may be able to script it to run automatically as part of a build process.

Personally I'd just write some wrappers using `[DllImport]`. Do you really need to access *everything* in the C++ library from C#? Often I've found you really only need to call a few functions, and the simplicity of dllimport is great